# Применение Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, многопоточность, tpl

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем особенность использования `Task.WhenAll` ?

Полазив в `msdn` понял, что он создает новую задачу, по завершении указанных задач в параметре, однако, по сути он ничего не создает, кроме некой ссылки типа `Task`, с которой я не могу понять что делать дальше. Если здесь создается просто ссылка, которой я должен присвоить в дальнейшем новый объект типа `Task`, то тогда проще вызвать (имхо)

```
Task.WaitAll(t, t1);
Task t2 = new Task(...);
```

или может быть я в неправильном направлении думаю. Подскажите пожалуйста пример использования этого метода. Спасибо.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Сначала я неправильно прочитал вопрос и ответил про `WaitAll`.

Допустим есть несколько экземплров `Task<T>`, каждый из которых выполняет действие и возвращает результат. Затем, все эти результаты надо как-то обработать. `WhenAll` создаёт таск, который заканчивается, когда заканчиваются все таски в него переданные. При этом результатом этого таска будет массив результатов тасков аргументов.

Также можно проанализировать состояние переданных тасков, их исключения и так далее.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t1 = new Task<int>(DoSomething1);
    var t2 = new Task<int>(DoSomething2);

    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();

    var t3 = Task.WhenAll(t1,t2);

    Console.WriteLine(t3.Result.Sum());
}

private static int DoSomething2()
{
    return 3;
}

private static int DoSomething1()
{
    return 5;
}
```

Comment: Это понятно. Однако я имел в виду метод WhenAll

Comment: Извините, это я неправильно прочитал. Сейчас отвечу и по теме.

Comment: Ответил по тому, что действительно спрашивали.

Comment: Спасибо, отлично.

Comment: @АнтонБуторин: прочитал про WaitAll. Предлагаю вам задать самостоятельно вопрос и дать ответ. Не пропадать же хорошему ответу ))

Answer (score 4):

Как это вы не можете понять, что делать с объектом типа Task?

С любой задачей можно сделать три вещи:

1. дождаться ее окончания асинхронно

   ```
   await Task.WhenAll(a1, a2);
   // К этому моменту a1 и a2 уже завершились
   ```
2. дождаться ее окончания синхронно (не очень полезный вариант - привожу для полноты картины)

   ```
   Task.WhenAll(a1, a2).Wait(); // тоже самое, что и Task.WaitAll(a1, a2)
   ```
3. сформировать продолжение

   ```
   var a3 = Task.WhenAll(a1, a2).ContinueWith(...);
   ```

Comment: В своем вопросе я имел в виду, что не могу понять что за объект типа `Task<int[]>` возвращается. Может быть я криво выразился

Comment: Ну, про типизированный Task вам уже написали выше.

Comment: Ну да, это то что меня и интересовало