# Запуск нескольких задач только в одном потоке

Tags: c#, async-await, tpl, multiprocessing

В момент времени запускаются 300 тасков ( этот запуск происходит периодически в пару минут). Метод, который выполняется внутри таска, производит несколько асинхронных запросов к внешнему источнику.  Учитывая, что тасков много, а ответ от внешнего источника может быть на протяжении нескольких минут, то из-за этого создаются лишние потоки. Лишние в том плане, что одновременно рабочей машиной они обрабатываться не могут и приходится тратить время на переключение между ними. Вопрос в том, как я могу ограничить количество потоков, ( т.е. запускать в одном потоке 15 тасков так как рабочая станция позволяет выполнять паралельно 20 потоков) которые будут задействованы для обработки этих тасков.
Возможные варианты это ограничение количества потоков в ThreadPool или же запуск через Parallel.For с установкой параметра MaxDegreeOfParallelism. 
Но есть условие, что окончившаяся асинхронная операция должна продолжить работу в потоке в котором она началась/была запущена. Буду рад любой помощи или источникам, где я смогу увидеть идею реализации.

Upd.
Относительно того, почему создаётся поток для запуска асинхронной операции. Источников к которым происходят запросы - много и они разные. Поэтому один экземпляр, который запускается через Task.Run() это обращение только к одному внешнему источнику. Т.е. 300 тасков это 300 разных источников. Также эти данные далее обрабатываются со своей логикой.

Comment: То есть вы создаете поток для запуска асинхронной операции? Зачем? Запускайте все асинхронные операции в своем потоке асинхронно.

Comment: Уточнил, спасибо

Comment: Все ещё не ясно, почему вы не хотите стартануть все таски со своего потока, для чего новые потоки создаете? Можно пример кода?

Comment: Плюсую к "запустить все триста в одном потоке, потом собрать результат" https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/438952/213987

Comment: Если у вас создаются потоки, значит ваши обращения к внешним источникам cpu bound, а не io bound, т.е. фактически синхронные, если вы хотите создать кучу тасков, и не плодить потоки, сделайти так, чтобы обращения в внешним источникам были реально асинхронные.

Comment: Ну если хотите именно так то стандартными средствами не получится, только если писать свой task манагер. Но Вы уверены что вам нужно реализовать имени так?